# Using switch to assign an instance variable

Tags: swift, switch-statement, instance, instance-variables

I'd be grateful for any help - been racking my brains for days and I can't see why this isn't working.

Essentially, I have a main view controller which will be controlled by different classes depending on which game the user selects

'classic'
'unlimited'
'timed'

When the user button is pushed, it needs to flick through the options and assign an instance of the class to a variable 'brain'.

this is what I have:

```
var brain = GuessMeComparer()

func switcher (random:String) {

switch random {

case "Classic": self.brain = ClassicBrain()
case "unlimited": self.brain = GuessMeComparer()
case "timed": self.brain = TimedBrain()

default:break

}
}
```

I get the error 'cannot assign a value of type 'ClassicBrain' to a value of type 'GuessMeComparer'.

All I can think of is that you cannot assign instance variables using switch?

Any help would be great, cheers!

Comment: It'd help to know the types of these variables. Are the `GuessMeComparer` and `ClassicBrain` of the same predecessor?

Comment: What do `GuessMeComparer`, `ClassicBrain`, `GuessMeComparer` and `TimedBrain` inherit from?

Comment: They are all custom classes which I have not subclassed from any superclasses so do not inherit from anything....I think this is what my issue when trying to set 'brain'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using AnyObject will work but – as vadian is saying – will force you to cast to a specific type later. A better option will be abstract a common interface for all the brain classes in a swift protocol, e.g.:

```
protocol BrainProtocol {
   // common interface here
   ...
}

class /* or struct */ ClassicBrain : BrainProtocol {
    // classic implementation here
    ...
}

class /* or struct */ TimedBrain : BrainProtocol {
    // timed implementation here
    ...
}

...

var brain : BrainProtocol
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift is a strong type language, the variable `brain` is declared as type `GuessMeComparer`.
 Once declared you cannot change the type.

To consider different types, declare the variable explicitly as generic type `AnyObject`.

```
 var brain : AnyObject = GuessMeComparer()
```

Now you can assign different types to the variable, but in many cases you have to cast the variable to a specific type later in the code.